# nopcommerce. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS при включении SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, https

Выполнил все рекомендации при переходе на SSL.
В web.config включил SSL, на сайте тоже включил SSL и указал безопасный адрес сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается добавлением строки в файл `WebConfig`

`<add key="Use_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="true" />`